# How to avoid PHP to auto-create attributes?

Tags: php, attributes

When doing this :

```
class MyClass
{
    public $myAttr;
}

$c = new MyClass();
$c->someStuff = 1;
```

I have no error message, no notice, no whatever to tell me "hey, I do not know someStuff !"

Is there anyway to make PHP less easy about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often define a `SafeObject` to inherit from, which dies when I attempt to read/write an undefined attribute:

```
class SafeObject {
    function __get($key) { die("Attempt to get nonexistent member $key"); }
    function __set($key, $value) { die("Attempt to set nonexistent member $key"); }
}
```

The idea being I should never actually call either of these methods during production code.

Answer (score 4):

Implement the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()` and tell them to spit a notice. These methods are called when you access a property that wasn't declared (or isn't visible).

```
public function __get($name) {
    trigger_error(__CLASS__ . " object has no such property $name", E_USER_NOTICE);
    return NULL;
}

public function __set($name, $value) {
    trigger_error(__CLASS__ . " object has no such property $name", E_USER_NOTICE);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to implement these magic methods for EACH class I write ??

Comment: You can do as meagar says, create a base class with these methods and then make all your classes inherit from the base class.